# Why is output image black after normalization?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, normalization, grayscale

I have many grayscale images that I want to normalize by using mean and standard deviation. I use the following process:

1. Calculate the image's mean and standard deviation.
2. Subtract the mean from the image.
3. Divide the resulting image by the standard deviation.

However, I got a black image as a result. What is wrong in my code?

```
    import cv2

    img = cv2.imread('E.png')   # read an image 
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img , cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # converting the image to grayscale image
    img = cv2.resize(gray_image, (60, 60))  # Resize the image to the size 60x60 pixels

    cv2.imwrite("Grayscale Image.png",img)  #To write the result  

    mean, stdDev = cv2.meanStdDev(img)  #Get Mean and Standard-deviation
    image = (img-mean)/stdDev  #Normalization process

    cv2.imwrite("Normalized Image.png",image)  #To write the result
```

Input image : [image: i1]

Grayscale output: [image: i2]

Normalized image output: [image: i3]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you save the image you need to consider the data type. To save the normalized image as png, you need to scale the normalized values to integer range (such as [0, 255]) or use image format that supports floating point format.

When using z-score normalization (as in your code), you could save it as png with

```
image -= image.min() 
image /= image.max()

image *= 255 # [0, 255] range
cv2.imwrite("Normalized Image.png", image)
```

Comment: "When you try to normalize the image all values are truncated to 0." -- that statement is false. In Python, the result of `cv2.meanStdDev` is a pair of 1x1 numpy arrays with dtype `float64`. Due to how type promotion works in numpy,  the result of `img - mean` is also `float64`, and so is the resulting image. Due to subtraction of mean, the values are however spread around 0, even going to negative. Floating point images are expected to have values in range [0,1] hence the cropping on save. | Your proposed change thus has no effect.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I missed that type conversion.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. It works for me, I really appreciate your help.